# Key Error while installing a python package

Tags: python, installation, keyerror

I got the following error while trying to install a python package on Windows 10:

> File "path\setup.py", line 91, in main  if icc or
> sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CC'] == 'icc': KeyError: 'CC'

The package required gcc, so I installed MinGW - this solved the gcc error, but I'm now getting this which I'm unsure whether or not it's related.

Any clues what could be causing this? I'm new to installing python stuff so I have no clue.

EDIT: So I've come to realise that the script is looking for a variable called "CC" (presumably this stands for C Compiler?) in my system configuration, but having inspected these variables there doesn't seem to be one.

Furthermore, it seems as though it expects the value of this variable to be "icc". Does this stand for Intel C Compiler? Will installing that fix the issue?

Comment: what was the package?

Comment: Hi, the package was MACS3 (https://github.com/macs3-project/MACS)